# How to get URL ID for posting AJAX to Controller

Tags: jquery

So I wrote an html tag, and then an ajax call:

```
<div class="test" data-id=""></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            let element = $(this);
            var serviceURL = '/AjaxTest/FirstAjax';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/actionid/delet,
                data: id: element.data("data-id")
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });

            function successFunc(data, status) {     
                alert(data);
            }

            function errorFunc() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

How do I pass the id of the data? like 1, 2 ,3

Comment: in the `data` you should send an object: `{id: element.data("data-id")}`. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType

Comment: When my Url an Id has, lets say post 1, /postid=1/, how do i pass it with data-id? what should be in the html tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/actionid/delet",
            data: { id:  $('.test').data('id') }
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });
```

or

```
        $.post( "/actionid/delet" , { id:  $('.test').data('id') } , function(result){
           // success here
        })
```

Comment: Even if your solution works, you should add some text explaining your solution, why it works and maybe also give some links to documentation or other similar things.

Answer (score 0):

First set an id for your element and then  use `$('#el').attr('data-id')`

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log($('#el').attr('data-id'))
            let element = $(this);
            var serviceURL = '/AjaxTest/FirstAjax';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/actionid/delet",
                data: { id: $('#el').attr('data-id') },
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });

            function successFunc(data, status) {
                alert(data);
            }

            function errorFunc() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="test" id="el" data-id="12"></div>
```

Comment: When my Url an Id has, lets say post 1, /postid=1/, how do i pass it with data-id? what should be in the html tag

Comment: You mean set the `data-id` of element?

Comment: ye right, so data-id = url-id, which will get post by ajax to delete it

Comment: Just use `$('#el').attr('data-id', yourData)` for example: `$('#el').attr('data-id',1)`

Comment: but the data-id is variable, its not always the same and should change when Im on a different post, u understand what I mean?

Comment: No I didn't catch you. Now you can get value of your element and send it to ajax parameter. what else do you want?

Comment: Where does value come from? I mean 1,2,3, that you want to send by ajax?

Comment: @earlybeard show me the whole URL with value. I think first you need to extract `id` and then use `$('#el').attr('data-id', yourData)`